Is it possible to make a dynamic change ( parameters labels names (different languages) on anylogic after compilation?
The question is above
I'm making compiled jar and need to quickly change parameters labels before compilation
It's necessary for me  because my jar app is multi language, and sometimes need to change the language of labels parameters names.

Did you mean different LOCALE, i18n? If yes try externalize them in different resources file post-fixed with locale.

Yes I mean a different locate. But I don't understand how to do it? When I have Anylogic project (in sources), then all my project is located in one Anylogic (*.alp) file. When I compiled it, it also becomes as 1 jar file (no resources files!) And as I see Anylogic does't have any options to copy this parameter captions to external file

My bad I missed to read Anylogic. My apologies as I am unaware of working with Anylogic.

pls only use the "anylogic" tag, else you confuse 1000s of SOF users :)

There is no automated way. What could work generally:

store different language options
use a batch-file command-line arg that specifies the required language
read and apply the arg into the model as needed

However, I do not think this can work for parameter descriptions (there is no setters for that). Instead, you could use Text elements and change the actual text based on the desired language at runtime via setters
